# How to change set pch in mapply in R

Tags: r

I would like to draw a dot plot with different shapes of points for different series of data (colors).

```
    mydf <- data.frame(V1=c(2,NA,NA,NA,6),V2=c(4,5,NA,7,6),V3=c(3,4,NA,3,9))

    plot("map",xlim=c(0,nrow(mydf)+1),ylim=c(min(mydf,na.rm=TRUE)-1,max(mydf,na.rm=TRUE)+1))
    mapply(function(x,color){
     dat <- na.omit(cbind(1:length(x),x))
      lines(dat[,1],dat[,2],type = "o", col=color)
    },mydf,c("red","blue","green"))
```

How to add legend to the plot with column names?
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really close , you need just to add a third parameter to your plot function:

```
plot_lines <- 
function(x,color,pch){
  dat <- na.omit(cbind(1:length(x),x))
  lines(dat[,1],dat[,2],type = "o", col=color,pch=pch)
}
```

Thenk you call it using :

```
mapply(plot_lines,mydf,c("red","blue","green"),pch=c(20,10,18))
```

[image]